# Is there any advantage to limiting the length of a password if the password is stored as a hash?

Tags: database, security, passwords

I've seen a lot of sites that limit the length of a password to something like 10 or 12 characters. I understand that that could be a sign that they are storing the password in plain text and they limit the length because they think it will save space, but if they are storing a password as a hash, is there any advantage to this limit?

**Edit:** I am quite aware that longer passwords are stronger and that a hash is a hash, and the length is the same regardless of the input. My *real* question here is is there some sort of convoluted reason that system designers use to rationalize this inherently insecure practice?

Comment: With the new `Outlook.com` interface I'm suddenly finding it complains if I enter more than 16 characters of my Windows Live password. They are Microsoft, so I doubt they store them in plain text. I guess the only alternative is that they've only been hashing the first 16 characters all along...

Comment: Why *would* you limit the length? (Except to a data-sanity limit, like 80) Please google for "horse battery staple correct", which is well, more than 12 characters.

Comment: I'm not saying you *would* limit the length, I'm asking if there's any sort of convoluted reason that backend designers are using to rationalize limiting password length.

Comment: @NickAnderegg My "best answer" is: a mindset that has not been corrected. Perhaps initially caused by *legacy restrictions or assumptions*. Most passwords still have other asinine requirements or restrictions ..

Comment: (I believe in "pass phrases" of which "passwords" tend to be a subset of. In any case, I have to vote as "Not Constructive" because I don't think there is a non-debatable cause that can be given as to why company/person/designer A chose limit X. A doctoral dissertation might be able to cover it ..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Not much of an advantage if they're storing it plain-text, either, really, in real life.

Comment: (Better to provide a reason for downvotes, IMO, so SO can be improved instead of just be a retaliatory playground.)

Answer (score 1):

A hash function takes an input of unspecified length, and returns a value of specified length. So no, the length of the input has no effect on the length of the output, as the length of the output is always the same for a given hash function.

Putting lower bounds on the length of passwords users can use is only ever to encourage users to use stronger passwords. Upper bounds, I couldn't say. Could be something against spam-bots, or they don't want to have to crunch a 200-character password for performance reasons.

And nobody stores passwords in plaintext.

Comment: No, but sometimes they store the password in a reversible format.

Comment: By "nobody" you mean except the ones that do. Because I've seen it in real life.

Comment: @DaveNewton this saddens me. it shows a fundamental misunderstanding of what a password actually is.

Comment: I'd say once a password is stored in plain text, it's no longer a password.

Comment: my point was more along the lines of 'a password is not a credential, nor a key. proof of (timely) knowledge of a password is a credential.'

Comment: People don't store passwords in plain text? I would love to live in that parallel universe where people actually know how to design secure systems. I actually tried to hack into that parallel universe, but the password was hashed.

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question, no, there is no benefit to deliberately implementing a low maximum length. What you'll find is that this ofen happens when there's a legacy dependency; your password can only be 10 chars long because it's back-ending into a system which implements this limit.

I suspect this is the case in scenarios such as [Tesco's](http://www.troyhunt.com/2012/07/lessons-in-website-security-anti.html). You've got 13 year old plus  system and, as you say, it's (allegedly) storing passwords in the clear and there are possibly multiple points where that 10 chat limit is implemented (DB col, SQL command params, etc).

The only reason I can possibly think of - and it's a stretch - is that text box with no lmit could allow the maximum request length to be exceeded but we're talking ridiculously long passwords here.